# ui-router & angular 1.5 : Browser back button fires $stateChangeStart twice and modifies history

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router with angular 1.5.

I have this issue where when I press browser BACK button, instead of going back in linear fashion it goes in weird order.

For example:

```
setOne: abstract
    State1: setOne.Result
    State2: setOne.Availability

setTwo: abstract
    State3: setTwo.Sim
    State4: setTwo.Boost

    Page order is : State1 > State2> State3 > State4
```

- Now suppose I start on State1 and continue to browse to setTwo.Boost
  ( last state ) & press browser back button, address bar flickers, and
  browser loads State3.
- After that if I press Back button again , then ideally it should go
  to State2 however it goes to State4 again.

So Expected History Behaviour should have been:

```
State4 > State3 > State2 > State 1
```

Actual behaviour:

```
State4 > State3 > State4> State2> State3 > State2 > State 1
```

I can see that $stateChangeStart is being called twice when Back button in browser pressed. The URL in the address bar flickers back and forth, and what appears to be an extra history entry shows up in the back button history. That modifies browser's last viewed page in history to current page from where I have clicked back button.

I went through slightly similar issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1780 however cant make out how to fix this issue.

Its just making me crazy where am I going wrong?

Any suggestions what I may have configured wrong here.

Comment: Did you manage to find the issue?